# Group By on multiple Inner Joins

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset that can be represented as a baseball card trading application.  There are two tables that track the cards that an individual owns, and that an individual wants.  If an individual owns more than one copy of a particular player's card there will be multiple rows in the `owned_cards` table (teams are excluded here).  If there is a card that an individual wants to add to their collection, a row is inserted in to the `wanted_cards` table.

`owned_cards`:

```
| owner | player     |
|-------|------------|
| Fred  | Babe Ruth  |
| Fred  | Babe Ruth  |
| Mary  | Lou Gehrig |
| Mary  | Yogi Berra |
| Mary  | Yogi Berra |
```

`wanted_cards`:

```
| owner | player     |
|-------|------------|
| Fred  | Lou Gehrig |
| Fred  | Yogi Berra |
| Mary  | Babe Ruth  |
```

I am trying to write a statement that will "auto match" individuals seeking trades.  If an individual owns more than one copy of a card, it is assumed that they would trade one of their extras.  Likewise, if they only posess one copy of a player's card, they would not offer that card for trade.  All cards are assumed to be of equal value.

```
SELECT fred_wants.player AS 'Fred Wants', mary_has.player AS 'Mary Has'
FROM wanted_cards fred_wants
INNER JOIN owned_cards mary_has ON fred_wants.owner = mary_has.owner
INNER JOIN wanted_cards mary_wants ON mary_has.owner = mary_wants.owner
INNER JOIN owned_cards fred_has ON fred_has.owner = mary_wants.owner
WHERE fred_wants.owner = 'Fred'
GROUP BY mary_has.player
HAVING COUNT(mary_has.player) > 1
```

Produces:

```
| Fred Wants | Mary Has   |
|------------|------------|
| Lou Gehrig | Babe Ruth  |
| Babe Ruth  | Lou Gehrig |
| Babe Ruth  | Yogi Berra |
```

Desired output:

```
| Fred Wants | Mary Has   |
|------------|------------|
| Babe Ruth  | Yogi Berra |
```

Fred wants a Lou Gehrig card, but Mary only has one so it is not up for trade.  Taking off the GROUP BY I see why the row is returned but I'm confused as to how there are so many rows generated; I thought the HAVING would pare it down.

Comment: Why would Fred want Babe Ruth !?!? Also, you're going to need a Primary Key before going too much further.

Comment: @Strawberry you're getting too far down in to the weeds and suggest you re-read the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample query which returns who has extras for the cards wanted by Fred:

```
select w.player as 'Fred Wants', t.owner as 'Who has extras'
from
wanted_cards as w
inner join
(
  select owner, player
  from owned_cards as o
  where o.owner <> 'Fred'
  group by owner, player
  having count(*) > 1
) as t
on (w.player = t.player)
where w.owner = 'Fred'
```

the main idea is to select all cards wanted by Fred and then find all extras for all other players

Comment: Thanks, the subquery I think is actually a bit more readable too